# Сложные числительные на "один"

Tags: грамматика

Как быть с изменением причастий в случае, если речь идет о 131 женщине?
В ходе нашего исследования было установлено, что из 131 пациентки, **соответствующей** критериям исследования, у 54 % была нарушена функция эндотелия.

Comment: Ваш текст вопроса не очень соответствует названию. Возможно из-за этого и возникло непонимание. Я в таких случаях отвечаю на вопрос, а не на заголовок. В любом случае рекомендую сделать авторскую правку вопроса.

Comment: Да, наверное я не очень точно сформулировала вопрос. Я не уверена, что говоря о 131 даме, использую единственное число. Хотя правила про 21, 31 и т.д.  -как о единственном числе. Показались корявыми и нелепыми мои предложения. Вот и решила уточнить.

Comment: Да, это совсем другое. Получается, Серж был ближе к пониманию вопроса, хотя тоже совершенно невпопад, имхо, ответил. Попробую сейчас дополнить ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Да, все правильно Вы написали. "Из *ста тридцати одной **пациентки, **соответствующей***". Это обычный родительный падеж от "соответствующая". А причастия склоняются подобно прилагательным. "Изменять" ничего не надо, что в женском роде, что в мужском. Просто задать вопрос *"из чего, кого?"* - "из соответствующей, большой, в**е**щей, пахучей, рыжей, дремучей..."- О ударное, Е - безударное после шипящих.

Уточните проблему, если Вам что-то непонятно.

upd

> Я не уверена, что говоря о 131 даме, использую единственное число.
>   Хотя правила про 21, 31 и т.д. -как о единственном числе.

Да, со всеми числительными, оканчивающимися на "один", "одна", "одно",  используется форма единственного числа существительного. Вообще согласование существительного всегда идет по последнему слову (цифре), это касается и рода, и числа, и, естественно, падежа.

Тому есть историческое объяснение: в те очень далекие времена, когда числительные были еще не отдельной частью речь, а особой группой существительных, наша фраза звучала бы примерно как *"**сто** пациенток и **тридцать** пациенток, и еще **одна пациентка**"*, - разумеется, с тогдашними формами. Потом все лишнее ушло, и появились составные числительные.

В именительном же все просто?
***И. Сто тридцать одна пациентка, соответствующая...***
А дальше - все по накатанному, просто склоняем всю конструкцию.
***Р. Ста тридцати одной пациентки, соответствующей...

Д. Ста тридцати одной пациентке, соответствующей...***
И. т. д.

А ощущение неправильности есть, согласен. Конструкция с этими причастиями на "-щий" - она тяжеловесна и довольно неуклюжа, да и трудновыговариваемое "соответствующий" - не сахар для легкости речи. Но числительное здесь ни при чем.

Answer (score 1):

Причастие в этом случае согласуется с числительным один.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38947/discussion-on-answer-by-----).